# Google Analytics 4 vs. UA: Why are Event and View Counts are Drastically Different?

Tags: google-tag-manager, google-analytics-4, universal-analytics

I had UA property and was loading it through GTM on web pages. Please refer below screenshot.
[image]

Now, I created new GA4 property and loading that also through GTM on web pages. Please refer below screenshot.
[image]

View count and event count is working same for UA & GA4 for main domain. It's max 10% difference which is fine. But If I compare total page view of subdomain for specific or each page for specific date, it is more than 90% off.

```
EX: 
Below is sub domain page view count for https://sub.xzy.com/page1
UA Count - 9000
UA Unique Count - 600

GA4 Count  - 200
GA4 Unique Count - 20
```

I read many articles but it says 10% off is fine but this is huge difference. Please help me if I missed anything.

I tried GTM debugging. While I open page using GTM debugger, it is firing both UA and GA4 tags. Even when I checked in real time data in analytics and GA4, both are getting correct view count.

This means GTM is running correctly and also analytics getting events from GTM. But not sure why view count is off for subdomain pages.

Comment: This doesn't look like subdomain issue. Because I tried to change GA4 domain to subdomain, still count is off for subdomain only. 

Looks when user from UK, it is not counting page view event for some. is that possible? if yes then how to resolve this?

Comment: it looks like you're misreading your reports in GA4. You're probably using a wrong dimension to filter your hostname.

Comment: I am using path in dimension to filter. Event if do not filter anything, total view count is different.

Comment: Good. Paths don't have domains. Unless you override the dimension. Use hostname to filter. Different total view count would be a separate issue.